# Is it possible to change the text color of text after a new line in a QListWidget?

Tags: python, list, qt, pyqt, qlistwidget

[image: Picture of what I am trying to achieve]

This is the delegate I am currently using to get two lines:

```
class AccountListDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def displayText(self, value, locale):
        text = super().displayText(value, locale)
        separator = ":"
        values = text.split(separator)
        return f"{values[0]}\n{values[1]}"
```

Is there a way to change the color of the bottom line?

Comment: It depends on how the text is painted by the delegate - we would need to see that part of the code. But in any case it definitely is possible to make the second line paint in a different color. But maybe you will need to rewrite the part of the code which is responsible for painting.

Comment: That is the entire delegate, I've relied on stylesheets for the formatting, other than that I haven't changed anything.